# Output command to clipboard?

Tags: clipboard

Noob(ish) to Linux here, and trying to pick up new/useful tricks; I was wondering if there's some way to send the output of a command straight to the clipboard?

Something similar to (pseudo-code):

`dircolors --print-database > clipboard`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11925/a-command-line-clipboard-copy-and-paste-utility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I asked I didn't realize there'd be any real difference between doing what I was looking to do when in WSL vs. "regular" (non-wsl) linux.

After looking over a bunch of references, in my WSL case, the easiest way seems to be to use window's `clip.exe`, rather than installing something like xclip, creating a bunch of aliases/scripts, etc.

I will try those as well on my Raspberry PI (Raspbian), but for now in WSL just doing this is working great:

`<command> | clip.exe`

i.e.

`dircolors --print-database | clip.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest here to use ***xclip*** :

1- You will need first to configure X11 display :

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config   
------------------
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
-----------------------
```

Restart the sshd service

```
service sshd restart
```

Open new ssh session with X11 forwarding enabled :

```
ssh -X <your_server>
```

2- Install libXmu-devel :

```
yum install libXmu-devel
```

OR on UBUNTU :

```
sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev
```

3- Clone xclip repository and compile the program :

```
git clone https://github.com/astrand/xclip.git
./bootstrap
./configure
make
make install
```

4- Add the command as an alias to your profile to create a shortcut that will save a lot of your time :

```
vi ~/.bashrc
---------------------
alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'
--------------------------
```

5- Use case :

```
cat file | pbcopy
```

Then the content of your file is copied to your clipboard